# Retrieve color of current texel in fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl, fragment-shader, fbo, multisampling

I want to **retrieve the color of the current texel in my fragment shader** so I can adapt the output color depending on it.

For example: if the current texel's color is *red* then set the color to *green*.
[image]
Above, you can see there are *two* triangles. One triangle is partially drawn **on** the other. You can see the superimposed portion is in green as, like I said, my fragment shader detected the color "red" so it set the output color to "green".

As you can see, my program works well. However, I'm a very beginner in OpenGL so I don't quite understand everything I wrote and I'm sure I did a few mistakes. I'd like your feedback.

What I did to achieve this:

1. Draw first triangle in a FBO
2. Copy the framebuffer to the draw framebuffer (= on screen)
3. Draw the second triangle directly on screen

At first I tried to **draw the two triangles directly on screen without a FBO but then I couldn't get the texel color with `texture2D()`** in my fragment shader.

Here is my code (I use **OpenGL 3.3**, **GLFW 3** and **GLEW**):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

const std::string WINDOW_TITLE = "Drawing color depending on current background pixel color";
const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

const std::string vertexShaderSource = R"(
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0f);
}
)";

const std::string fragmentShaderSource = R"(
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D renderedTexture;

void main()
{
    vec2 size = textureSize(renderedTexture, 0);
    vec2 position = gl_FragCoord.xy / size.xy;
    vec4 inputColor = texture2D(renderedTexture, position);

    if (inputColor[0] == 0.0f)
    {
        color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }
    else if (inputColor[0] == 1.0f)
    {
        color = vec4(0.1f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }
    else
    {
        color = vec4(0.8f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }
}
)";


GLFWwindow *setupWindow()
{
    GLFWwindow *window = nullptr;
    int width = 0, height = 0;

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, WINDOW_TITLE.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    return window;
}

GLuint compileShader(GLenum type, const std::string &source, std::string &errorLog)
{
    GLuint shader = 0;
    GLint compileSuccess = 0;
    const GLchar *sourceC = source.c_str();
    const std::size_t ERROR_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE = 512;
    GLchar errorLogBuffer[ERROR_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE]{};

    errorLog = "";

    shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &sourceC, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shader);

    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileSuccess);
    if (!compileSuccess)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, ERROR_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE, nullptr, errorLogBuffer);
        glDeleteShader(shader);

        errorLog = errorLogBuffer;

        return 0;
    }

    return shader;
}

GLuint compileShaderProgram(const std::string &vertexShaderSource, const std::string &fragmentShaderSource, std::string &errorLog)
{
    GLuint vertexShader{};
    GLuint fragmentShader{};
    GLuint shaderProgram{};
    GLint linkSuccess{};
    const std::size_t ERROR_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE = 512;
    GLchar errorLogBuffer[ERROR_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE]{};

    errorLog = "";

    vertexShader = compileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderSource, errorLog);
    if (vertexShader == 0)
        return 0;

    fragmentShader = compileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderSource, errorLog);
    if (fragmentShader == 0)
        return 0;

    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkSuccess);
    if (!linkSuccess)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, ERROR_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE, nullptr, errorLogBuffer);
        glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);

        errorLog = errorLogBuffer;

        return 0;
    }

    return shaderProgram;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GLFWwindow *window = setupWindow();
    std::string errorLog = "";
    GLuint shaderProgram = compileShaderProgram(vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource, errorLog);
    GLuint fbo = 0;
    GLuint fboTexture = 0;
    GLuint vao = 0;
    GLuint vbo = 0;
    GLenum drawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
    GLuint indicesBuffer = 0;
    GLushort indices[] = { 0,1,2, 3,4,5 };
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        // Bottom triangle (first triangle drawn)
        -0.5f, +0.0f,
        +0.5f, +0.0f,
        +0.0f, +0.5f,

        // Top triangle (second triangle drawn, partially ON the first one, and slighly above it)
        -0.5f, +0.2f,
        +0.5f, +0.2f,
        +0.0f, +0.8f,
    };


    /*
    ** Setup FBO
    */
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glGenTextures(1, &fboTexture);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTexture);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, fboTexture, 0);
    glDrawBuffers(sizeof(drawBuffers) / sizeof(GLenum), drawBuffers);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;


    /*
    ** Setup VAO and VBO
    */
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &indicesBuffer);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    /*
    ** Main loop
    */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        /*
        ** Draw first triangle in FBO (not on screen)
        */
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        glUseProgram(0);


        /*
        ** Copy the read framebuffer to the draw framebuffer (= on screen)
        */
        glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);


        /*
        ** Draw the second triangle directly on screen
        */
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, reinterpret_cast<const void*>(3 * sizeof(GLushort)));
        glUseProgram(0);


        /*
        ** Swap buffers
        */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }


    /**
    ** Free resources
    */
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &indicesBuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);

    glfwTerminate();


    return 0;
}
```

- Is it a good way of doing it?
- Is it called "*multisampling*"? From what I understand, you use FBO(s) with functions like `glTexImage2DMultisample()` to do multisampling. But even if I use an FBO, I use `glTexImage2D()` instead of `glTexImage2DMultisample()`. So?

Also, I don't quite understand **how the `uniform sampler2D renderedTexture;` in my fragment shader works**. I thought I needed to do something like:

```
GLuint texID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "renderedTexture");
glUniform1i(texID, 0);
```

to set the uniform variable, but I *don't* do it and it works. **Why?**

Finally, you might wonder why I want to do all this. Well, as I just started learning OpenGL, I do that as an "exercise" to solve my real problem: **write text on an image in a color with enough contrast so it can be readable** (e.g.: if you want to write some text on a white wall, write it in black, not in white, or you won't see it).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531185/reading-current-framebuffer

Comment: @genpfault So your suggestion is to use the GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch extension?

Comment: Kinda a non-starter unless you're on OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: @genpfault Even if I do my tests on desktop, I'm actually on OpenGL ES 2.0 (I'm coding an Android app).